# Cohomology with coefficient in a Lie algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-algebra-cohomology

For  a   topological  space X we can consider the coefficient of  singular  cohomology in a Lie  algebra A. Then we obtain a graded Lie  algebra, that is [x,y]=(-1)^i+j-1 [y,x], for homogeneous elements x and y of degree i and j.

My question :
Is there an example of two (nice) topological spaces X and y, with different homotopy type, such that they have the same homotopy group, homology group and cohomology rings. But their graded lie Algebra cohomologies are not isomorphic. By this question, I mean to what extent "cohomology with coefficient in Lie  algebras" is useful?

Another question what  is the graded lie  algebra structure for  this type of cohomology for X=CP^n with coefficient algebra A=M_{n}(C). 
Can one introduce me some related references?
Thank you

Comment: If the álgebra is the commutator lie algebra of an associative álgebra, you get just the commutator Lie álgebra of the usual cohomology ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is over a field $k$. Then what you are looking at is just the graded algebra $H^*(X,k)\otimes_k \mathfrak{g}$. If the cohomology algebras $H^*(X,k)$ and $H^*(Y,k)$ are isomorphic, so are their tensor products with $\mathfrak{g}$.

In particular, if $X=\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, you get the Lie algebra $k[x]/x^{n+1}\otimes_k \mathfrak{g}$, with $\deg(x)=2$.

Comment: Thank you, could you please give me some references? Another question:should I underestand from your answer that lie algebra coefficients does not contain new information to study the homotopy type of  a topological space?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a precise reference. I would look at the standard algebraic topology books (note that this is true for any algebra, not only Lie). And yes,  $k$-algebra coefficients do not bring any new information.